# ReportViewer vs CrystalReport .NET

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, reportviewer

I am looking for some comparisons between CrystalReport and ReportViewer.
Pros and Cons, and why I should use one over the other.

Has anyone stumbled upon such an article?  Or have some experience with both?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some good answers to this at [Compare SQL Server Reporting Services to Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports)