# Crystal Reports vs. Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports, report

I am developing a WPF application, and I need your advice.

I have to generate reports in my application.  What should I use, Crystal Reports or SQL Server Reporting Services?  Which one is better, and why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have used both
Although Crystal Reports is very well known and widely used. It can be a hassle at times (Not saying that SQL Server reporting services is not a hassle sometimes.)
Pros for Crystal Reports

- Many people use it and understand how to use it.
- Its ability in the creation of more basic to intermediate reports quickly is a plus.
- Even if you don't know SQL you can still fiddle with Crystal Reports to get the result you want, and flatten out the data.
- Supports Dynamic Cascading Prompts (version XI and Higher)
- Supports Web Viewer, ActiveX, Java and HTML.

Cons for Crystal Reports

- Crystal's Report Design Component seems to be full of strange scenarios.
- I believe because the software has
  changed hands so many times. 
  Documentation is pretty limited for
  the Report Design Component.
- A beginner can definitely create a
  nice formatted report quickly and
  easily, but when it comes to more
  complex reports where performance is
  needed.  Going back to understanding
  SQL is necessary.

Pros for SQL Server Reporting

- Web Based Reporting Server
- Report Rendering Engine supports a
  number of formats (Excel, HTML,
  Image, and more)
- Publishing and scheduling is a part
  of Reporting Services. In crystal you
  need Crystal Reports Server or
  Business Objects Enterprise for
  Publishing and scheduling.  Or you
  would need to create your own custom
  app)
- Parameter prompting is nicer in my
  opinion
- Saved Data sources can be accessed by
  excel users.
- User login and permissions are built in.
- Subscriptions are a built in feature

Cons for SQL Server Reporting

- It can sometimes be a pain to implement
- the Report builder feature for building simple reports is somewhat limited
- The best report builder is Visual Studio's Business Intelligence Studio. This is only a con because for a beginning end user this could seem overwhelming

In all SQL Server Reporting Services is my pick.

Answer (score 3):

I use SSRS in a big project and start using it from 3 years ago. it is a very good solution. I recommend you to use SSRS not Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 2):

In the Following Link, the first two answers (one who supports SSRS and the other who supports CR) and they are giving their opinion about it.

[Compare SQL Server Reporting Services to Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports)

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports - **780 MB**
Report Builder - **30 MB** (still better and easier to use)