# reporting services or crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

i am presently working on a project to generate invoice reports in visual studio 2010.
I am confused whether to use crystal reports or reporting services(rdlc) to generate reports.
The reports are required to be generated for a manufacturing unit(print, save all options are necessary).
Which one is better to use as per my needs?

Comment: This previous question may assist you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659729/crystal-reports-vs-microsoft-sql-server-reporting-services/2659998#2659998

Comment: Nice summation of pro's / con's of Crystal & RDLC in the above link!

Answer (score 0):

If you're printing invoices, I would consider using Crystal Reports first. It will allow for easier formatting and viewing within a Windows app.

If you know Reporting Services REALLY WELL, you can accomplish what you're wanting to do, but if you're new to both, I believe you'll be happier in the end using Crystal Reports. You will get better, easier results with less effort.

Your question is open for debate, so this is only an opinion.

Comment: You might consider looking at Report Runner Web Portal, too... http://www.reportrunner.com

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the local reporting services (RDLC) and only use the full blown report server when necessary.  You have a viewer for RDLC with options to print and save in various formats and you can easily stream the reports to PDF.

The version of Crystal that comes "stock" with VS is limited and the full versions are a bit pricey for my taste.  I have been able to do everything I have needed with reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/). It will save you a lot of time compared to Crystal or SSRS. And you can do more with it.

The unique difference is with Windward you design the reports in Microsoft Word, Excel, or PowerPoint. So it's a very powerful easy to use design tool you already know. And because Word/Excel/PPT are free-form, [you can do most anything for your final report](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/01/banded-reports-are-evil.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to disagree with everyone (so far).  I am not familiar with Windward Reports, so I won't comment on that, but I am familiar with Crystal Reports in VS2005.  It is clunky, difficult to use and comes with more headaches.  I learned Crystal Reports using an Enterprise version (which is very expensive) and having to work with this stripped down version is a nightmare.

I have completed a couple of different reports using Reporting Services and Stored Procedures and it is a walk in the park compared to doing the same thing using Crystal.  Even if you don't know Reporting Services all that well, I'm sure you'll be fine.  When I was stuck, I was able to find answers here on Stack Overflow.  Any one of the Step by Step books are helpful as well.