# Advantages of Reporting service Over Crystal Report or vice versa

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am doing  an enterprise application containing Report module and i confused to use Crystal report or Reporting Service for the same.Which one is better to implement, faster in output and suppressing report.

Please Help

Comment: There are many similar questions if you search stackoverflow. One of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659729/crystal-reports-vs-microsoft-sql-server-reporting-services