# How Many Types Of Reports Available in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Currently Building `ASP.NET MVC` Application, I want to use reporting services.
How many types of reports we create in `asp.net MVC` except `SAP Crystal Reports`.

Which `Reporting Services` is efficient in `ASP.NET MVC`?
I Have some idea about `Crystal Reports`, but don not know "How to create Crystal Reports".

Comment: Actually Crystal Reports as owned by SAP nowadays are showing severe latency issue and VS completely freezes while you use them. So, its better to use any inbuilt Reporting system by VS or anything other than CR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking so many thing in this question. There are so many reporting services, but good to use eigher crystal report or reporting service (In built functionality in visual studio or use SSRS (extension of reporting services)).

> How many types of reports we create in asp.net MVC except SAP Crystal
>   Reports

Any report you can create like simple report, cross-tab report , map or graph design, multiple report in a single reports etc. Also convert into any format like pdf, excel or word etc.

> Which Reporting Services is efficient in ASP.NET MVC?

[Both is good in terms of have prop and cons.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659729/crystal-reports-vs-microsoft-sql-server-reporting-services)

If you have knowledge and confident about crystal report, I suggest go with that rather than understand new one. After understand the crystal report or say good developer in `Crystal report`, then understand the `Reporting Services`, which you learn faster on that level.

**Updated : Step by step learn `Crystal reports`**

http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-stepbystep.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its

Comment: need Some Guidelines How To Create Crystal Reports ? How To Design Custom Reports and How To Bind data?