# SSRS vs Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, ssrs-2008

Please, can anyone tell me what are the main differences between SSRS 2005 & Crystal Reports?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208589/new-project-ssrs-vs-crystal-reports

Comment: two great links there from @nonnb. Try and go with SSRS2008 if you can, there is a reasonable jump in functionality between that and SSRS2005.

Answer (score 5):

the main differences are:

1. **SSRS is tabled-base design pattern but in CR you can place objects every where freely.**
2. Export to Excel in SSRS works better than CR, CR will disappoint you to use this future.
3. CR have several options to manage your sections for example(underlying following section) is very useful but there is no such an option in SSRS, and many more options in CR for Page Managements.
4. CR has Client Side Report Creation API(CRAXDDRT) which can let your customers modify and create new Reports.
5. CR using Formula in C and basic and SSRS using Expressions.
6. SSRS is very compatible with Sharepoint list and can Create reports based on Lists.
7. Cross Tables in CR vs Matrix Reprts in SSRS.
8. Both of them support OLAP Connections.

Comment: 9. Crystal Reports has not been updated since 2013 and has a $700+ CAL cost while SSRS is included free via SQL Server

Comment: SSRS will soon be able to host Power BI in SP1 / SP2 2016 - also free via SQL Server

Answer (score -3):

The main diffrences are

1. With ssrs ,editing reports that contain data is almost impossible.With CR is easy
2. SSRS requires good knowledge of SQL.
3. SSRS is designed to work only when you want view the reports online.It doesn't provide any tools for offline viewing.
4. SSRS reports  can only be exported to excel sheets and PDF's,while CR's can can be exported to word document, and even powerpoint presentations

Comment: Half of what this person stated on SSRS is completely false.  I think they don't even know SSRS at all reading what they stated.