# Difference between SSRS and Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I'm going to develop an application...Just wondering...

What are the difference between SSRS and Crystal Report?[Visual Studio 2010]

Can you provide pros and cons?

Comment: Already answered in depth in this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports

Comment: Go through these links :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814376/ssrs-vs-crystal-reports
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports

Answer (score 9):

I have used both Although Crystal Reports is very well know and widely used. It can be a hassle at times (Not saying that SQL Server reporting services is not a hassle sometimes.)

**Pros for Crystal Reports**

- May people use it and understand how to use it. Its ability in the
  creation of more basic to intermediate reports quickly is a plus.
  Even if you don't know SQL you can still fiddle with Crystal Reports
  to get the result you want, and flatten out the data. Supports
  Dynamic Cascading Prompts (version XI and Higher) Supports Web
  Viewer, ActiveX, Java and HTML.

**Cons for Crystal Reports**

- Crystal's Report Design Component seems to be full of strange
  scenarios. I believe because the software has changed hands so many
  times. Documentation is pretty limited for the Report Design
  Component. A beginner can definitely create a nice formatted report
  quickly and easily, but when it comes to more complex reports where
  performance is needed. Going back to understanding SQL is necessary.

**Pros for SQL Server Reporting**

- Web Based Reporting Server Report Rendering Engine supports a number
  of formats (Excel, HTML, Image, and more) Publishing and scheduling
  is a part of Reporting Services. In crystal you need Crystal Reports
  Server or Business Objects Enterprise for Publishing and scheduling.
  Or you would need to create your own custom app) Parameter prompting
  is nicer in my opinion Saved Data sources can be accessed by excel
  users. User login an permissions are built in. Subscriptions are a
  built in feature

**Cons for SQL Server Reporting**

- It can sometimes be a pain to implement the Report builder feature
  for building simple reports is somewhat limited The best report
  builder is Visual Studio's Business Intelligence Studio. This is only
  a con because for a beginning end user this could seem overwhelming

In all SQL Server Reporting Services is my pick.

Comment: SSRS is inevitable.  Nice summation of current technical limitations http://www.crystalmigrater.com/ssrslimitations.html

Comment: Interesting that the stackoverflow index (ie 'crystal report' vs 'ssrs' as a search term) are about even.