# Reports options: C# linq to entities web application

Tags: c#, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have a web application that was build in c# and uses queries in L2E. I need some basic reports with date parameters. What are my options? And if possibole as a scond need: printing those reports to CSV? Thanks

Updates: 
I have done some reading: [Compare SQL Server Reporting Services to Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports)

and I am thinking to do RDL reports. Can anyone give me steps to do start doing so in vs2008? I am using ms SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Crystal reports is not free. the SSRS is free with ms sql even the express edition. 
some links that helped:

[Compare SQL Server Reporting Services to Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports)

and just used report builder instead of link 2 entities.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with L2E unfortunately. Is that a form of database or merely the language used to query the database? Is the database SQL server?

Crystal Reports is pretty good for customer facing reports but not so much for tabular/mi style reporting (especially exporting). SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) i find better for that.

If your only requirement is for .csv exports (not to display on screen beforehand) you may even want to consider sql views/jobs/stored procedures. I use bcp / sqlcmd in conjunction with views to create data extracts from quite a few SQL dbs.

Comment: L2E means: Linq to Entities (similar to linq to sql), but my main requirement is to display on the web application. thanks