# Browser support for Crystal report viewer vs MS Reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am planning to add report functionality to Asp.net internet web application. Looking for suggestions from others what report control to proceed with ? MS Report viewer or Crystal reports . I am concerned about scalability ,Browser support etc...

Comment: Not sure how this is different than: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports

Comment: Well , Thanks !! The above link provides answers to most of my questions to choose between Crystal Report vs SSRS Report viewer of MSReportviewer configured run locally (.rdlc file).

Comment: While Jamie's linked question provides some good answers, you may want to check SSRS browser support - my experience of one of the older versions of SSRS was that the support for non-Microsoft browsers wasn't very good.

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble with SSRS reports in any browser but Internet Explorer. Crystal on the other hand i've had working well in Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

I don't think i'd use that as the main factor in deciding which reporting solution to use.