# How to generate report on a button click in an asp.net website in visual studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, reportviewer

I am building a billing software for school. I am having problems on printing the bill.

- 1.Should I use report viewer or Crystal Report ??  Whichever I use I have to bind report source to one of the table in my sql server
  database.
- 2.How can i do this??
- 3.Also I want to generate bill on a button click. How can I do this??

Comment: Does it specifically have to be Crystal reports or can it be SSRS(SQL Server Reporting Services)?

Comment: I haven't researched about SSRS. But in my application i want to create a bill on click of a button. Can SSRS be modified like that??

Comment: Ok Deni , I have to use either ReportViewer or CrystalReport

Comment: SQL Server 2008..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you want to use SSRS or Crystal is entirely up to you, if you want to know the advantages/disadvantages of the two I recommend reading - [Compare SQL Server Reporting Services to Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports).

You will find that a large number of developers choose to go for SSRS, if you feel the same here's a nice step-by-step example to get you started - [RDLC Report in ASP.net](http://kishor-naik-dotnet.blogspot.com/2011/06/aspnet-rdlc-report-in-aspnet.html)