# Is SAp Bo Universe similar to SSRS DAta Source views

Tags: database-design, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I just wondering whether the Business object universe is a concept similar to SSRS DAta source view?
Can anybody compare the difference /similarity between these 2 tools?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Reporting Services reports themselves do not have a "Data Source View". Reporting Services used to have a feature called Report Models that was similar in some respects to the BO Universe (and did use something called a Data Source View) but this has been deprecated from SQL Server 2012 onwards. A more comparable feature for SQL Server 2012 would be the BI Semantic Model, which is used by Microsoft's Power View visualisation tool.

If you are looking for a comparison between SSRS and Business Objects Crystal Reports, there is one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports).