# Float Number Precision in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports, datatable, double

I'm implementing a report which contains a table with some columns and I use a datatable and a dataAdapter to fill this table.The problem which I can not find a solution for it is that one of the fields which is a float number in the database (Like this: 0.32546)doesn't have enough precision when is displayed in the report (Like:0.32).What is your suggestion to view this number totally?

Here is the screenshot of my dataset,which "Result_num" is the float field(I've tested both System.single and system.double):
[image]

P.S. The data shown in the datatable is complete and with the desired precision.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

At first I highly recommend to not make use of Crystal-Report! [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports) is why?!

But for now make sure that the type of the field you are using is `Numeric`.
then change your decimal numbers by right clicking on the filed and move forward like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot,I checked this solution before ,but unluckily There isn't a Number tab when I open Format object!

Comment: Are you Sure about the DataType you are using?

Comment: It is Float in the database and also System.Single inthe datatable!

Comment: Is it possible to send the value from your code to a "ParameterField"? in this way you will send the value of your data and therefore manipulating the data will be too easy from your c#/vb code.

Comment: I think it's the only solution I have!I'm going to check it.Thanks for your concern.