# Functional alternative to Crystal Reports

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, report

Our company generates a lot of nice looking reports. Currently most of these are done via Crystal Reports.

I find the software bloated and difficult to use.

Is there any alternate software out there that can build a GUI pdf report with placeholders for information to be input (preferably via JSON).

Comment: I've heard of tablau so far, but nothing else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare SQL Server Reporting Services to Crystal Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports)

Comment: you can try [ActiveReports](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ActiveReports/)

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer is relevant only if your goal is to do pdf reports.

We were having same troubles using crystal or telerik reports and came to conclusion that using html -> pdf conversion approach is just most productive.

[wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org) is great for it. You can basically assemble html report in (asp.net razor, java...), send it to wkthtmltopdf console application and get back pdf.

We went little bit further with this approach and implemented [jsreport](http://jsreport.net) reporting server. It additionally includes html report designer, JSON REST API, javascript templating engines interpreter and also maintains report templates for you.