# What exactly is SSRS for?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I have heard a lot about SSRS tool , and am planning to use it in my project for retrieving reports. however, I am not clear about why SSRS should be used. 
What is it that SSRS has, that I should use it?
What about Crystal Reports? Are they comparable?

Thanks!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. Also please read [ask] in [help].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare SQL Server Reporting Services to Crystal Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Pred that this is a bit of a generic question, but nevertheless:

SSRS is a Microsoft tool that has good integration with their platform, such as sql server, .NET, and so on.

Crystal Reports is now owned by Business Objects, who specialize in business intelligence software.

For basic reports, either is fine. I find that Crystal Reports / Business Objects works better for more advanced reporting. I'd lean towards SSRS if you're already on a Microsoft stack.